# downgrade gedit from 3.10 to 3.6

Tags: 14.04, gedit, downgrade

I am on ubuntu 14.04 and gedit 3.10 
In a previous post I asked why zencoding plugin did not work on my version of gedit.

But now I realized that from this list for 3.8 ~ 3.10 zencoding is not offered: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ThirdPartyPlugins-v3.8

while in this list from 3.0 ~ 3.6 it is https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ThirdPartyPlugins-v3.0

How can I downgrade my version of gedit?

Answer (score 2):

**The `make` command fails in my Ubuntu Vivid. I suspect that the libraries are too new for Gedit 3.16. Maybe you have luck with Trusty.**

1. Download the latest 3.6 version from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/3.6/)

   ```
   cd; wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/3.6/gedit-3.6.2.tar.xz
   ```
2. Install the development libraries

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep gedit
   ```
3. Extract the archive

   ```
   tar xf gedit-3.6.2.tar.xz
   ```
4. Configure with `--prefix=/usr/local` to protect your existing installation

   ```
   cd gedit-3.6.2
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
   ```
5. Build

   ```
   make
   ```
6. If there was no error in the previous steps, install via `checkinstall` and not with `sudo make install`, `checkinstall` creates and installs a deb package for you

   ```
   sudu apt-get install checkinstall
   sudo checkinstall
   ```
7. Create a desktop file

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/gedit36.desktop
   ```

   Add the lines below

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Gedit
   GenericName=Text Editor
   X-GNOME-FullName=
   Comment=
   Exec=/usr/local/bin/gedit
   Icon=gedit
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=GNOME;
   StartupNotify=true
   X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gedit
   ```

Comment: Have you started a `sudo apt-get build-dep gedit`

Comment: yes, i went all the way thru.  but how do i launch this now?

Comment: The program 'gedit' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gedit

Comment: `sudo checkinstall` was successfully?

Comment: ` sudo checkinstall

checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
           This software is released under the GNU GPL.


The package documentation directory ./doc-pak does not exist. 
Should I create a default set of package docs?  [y]: y

Preparing package documentation...OK

Please write a description for the package.
End your description with an empty line or EOF.
>> gedit-3.6.2
>> ^C

*** SIGINT received ***

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Try a `sudo make install`

Comment: make[3]: *** [gedit-enum-types.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ggg/Downloads/gedit-3.6.2/gedit'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ggg/Downloads/gedit-3.6.2/gedit'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ggg/Downloads/gedit-3.6.2/gedit'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27280/discussion-between-a-b-and-t-q).

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep gedit` produces "Reading package lists... Done E: Unable to find a source package for gedit" on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. What can I do?