# Install `gedit-plugin` for a downgraded version of gedit

Tags: 16.04, gedit, plugins

Using [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664614/downgrade-gedit-from-3-10-to-3-6) instructions, I could get gedit 3.10.4 to run on ubuntu 16.04.

Now, I need to install the version of `gedit-plugins` that corresponds to gedit 3.10.4. The sources are [here](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit-plugins/refs/tags) but I have not been able to get them to work.

More precisely, I did:

```
dpkg: error processing package gedit-plugins (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gedit-plugins
cd Downloads/
cd gedit-plugins-3.10.1/
./autogen.sh
```

But I get:

```
Configuration:

    Source code location:   .
    Compiler:               gcc
    Prefix:         /usr/local
    Python Plugins Support: yes
    Plugins:                bookmarks bracketcompletion charmap codecomment colorpicker colorschemer commander dashboard drawspaces joinlines multiedit smartspaces textsize wordcompletion 

    Disabled plugins:       synctex (dbus-python not found), terminal (vte not found), git (libgit2-glib not found)

Note: you have to install these plugins into the same prefix as your gedit
installation (probably /usr if you're using your distro packages, /usr/local
if you have compiled it on your own).
```

So here is my question: how can I have `gedit-plugins` up and running?
*In particular, I need the terminal plugin to work*.

---

P.S. I have already installed `libvte-dev`

## Edit (wintermute's answer below)

yes, I have tried. Here is what I got:

```
Preparing to unpack gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gedit-plugins (3.10.1-1ubuntu2) over (3.10.1-1ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gedit-plugins:
 gedit-plugins depends on python3.4; however:
  Package python3.4 is not installed.
 gedit-plugins depends on python3 (<< 3.5); however:
  Version of python3 on system is 3.5.1-3.
 gedit-plugins depends on gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90; however:
  Package gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 is not installed.
 gedit-plugins depends on gir1.2-vte-2.90; however:
  Package gir1.2-vte-2.90 is not installed.
 gedit-plugins depends on gir1.2-zeitgeist-2.0; however:
  Package gir1.2-zeitgeist-2.0 is not installed.
```

Comment: Try apt-get install `gedit-plugins:version`, where version is the correct version number for gedit.

Comment: As far I understand you want to `./configure --prefix/usr --with-plugins=terminal && make && make install

Comment: I didn't mean gedit's version instead look up what versions of gedit and gedit-plugins work together and write that version there.

Comment: @Force: thanks! the correct version [seems](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit-plugins) to be 3.10.1-1ubuntu2  but `apt-get install gedit-plugins:3.10.1-1ubuntu2` gives `E: Unable to locate package gedit-plugins:3.10.1-1ubuntu2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gedit-plugins:3.10.1-1ubuntu2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gedit-plugins:3.10.1-1ubuntu2'`

Comment: oops, my bad equal sign there the colon is for arch (amd64,i386, etc)

Comment: @Force: Remenber that I am using 16.04: `sudo apt-cache madison gedit-plugins` returns `gedit-plugins |   3.18.0-1 | http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages`, but I want to install gedit-plugins for a *downgraded* version of gedit

Comment: remove that -1ubuntu2 part at the end

Comment: still not~~~~;((

Comment: Did you run the `autogen.sh` ?

Comment: Yeah there many dependencies you might want to wiggle through all of em you can restart that configure again and again. it even gives me on my machine some unmet deps.

Comment: @user2413 found a solution for you which definetively works. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to find out that the build process isn't so easy to solve. However I found another approach for you to get the old version of `gedit` and `gedit-r-plugin` up and running.

First removing the traces of your gedit compiling and installing tries (change the paths respectively to fit your situation).

```
cd ~/your build dir of gedit-plugins/
sudo make uninstall
cd ~/your build dir of gedit/
sudo make uninstall
```

The next command uninstalls the eventually existing 3.18.3 version of `gedit`, `gedit-dev`, `gedit-plugins` and `gedit-common`.

```
sudo apt-get remove gedit gedit-dev gedit-plugins gedit-common
```

Best to do the following steps in a clean seperate directory.

Now downloading the proper dependencies package for `gedit-common 3.10.4` and installing it.

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gedit/gedit-common_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i gedit-common_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_all.deb
```

Then downloading the proper `gedit 3.10.4` package and installing it

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gedit/gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb
```

And downloading the proper `gedit-dev 3.10.4` package and installing it.

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gedit/gedit-dev_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gedit-dev_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb
```

Finaly downloading the proper `gedit-plugins 3.10.1` package

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gedit-plugins/gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

We need to unpack this downloaded .deb file because we need to do two changes (sudo keps the packages owner intact).

```
sudo dpkg-deb -R gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb tmp
```

First we are editing `tmp/DEBIAN/control` and change `python3 (<< 3.5), python3 (>= 3.4~), python3.4` to `python3 (>= 3.5~), python3.5`.

```
sudo nano tmp/DEBIAN/control
```

Then we edit `tmp/DEBIAN/postinst`and change `py3compile -p gedit-plugins /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins -V 3.4` to `py3compile -p gedit-plugins /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins -V 3.5`.

```
sudo nano tmp/DEBIAN/postinst
```

Now we can pack a new .deb file.

```
sudo dpkg-deb -b tmp gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

And changing ownership of the new .deb file (replace username with your username)

```
sudo chown username:username gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Now finally installing it.

```
sudo dpkg -i gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

And now we download the proper `gedit-r-plugin 0.8.0.2` package and install it.

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gedit-r-plugin/gedit-r-plugin_0.8.0.2-Gtk3-Python3-1ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i gedit-r-plugin_0.8.0.2-Gtk3-Python3-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Only thing now left is protecting this all from upgrading.

```
sudo apt-mark hold gedit-common gedit gedit-dev gedit-plugins gedit-r-plugin
```

Comment: Do you have all sources enabled ? Ubuntu source, proposed, backport, cannonical etc ?

Comment: let me post my soures.list file. added it to my answer @user2413

Comment: Btw why youre trying to compile that old version of gedit ?

Comment: Finaly found the culprit which prevented the terminal from being build, you might want to have a look again at my answer. @user2413

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39139/discussion-between-videonauth-and-user2413).

Comment: Indded i got it working. just make sure to follow step by step and do the edits right .

Comment: Im in chat if you want to enter for questions

Comment: Thanks again for your work: it works great! I'm sure many people would find this (and [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/766055/how-do-i-downgrade-gedit-to-a-previous-3-10-4-version-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/766056#766056) answer) extremely helpfull!

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out -- but how do I find the plugin build directory?  I point my terminal to `/usr/share/gedit` and `make uninstall` gives me `make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.`

Comment: You only would need this step if you tried to build gedit from source before and then the build directories would be in your home folder. If not you can skip this step. or have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/766055/how-do-i-downgrade-gedit-to-a-previous-3-10-4-version-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) where i even provided a script to do the downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the right version of the package compiled for an older release and installing it manually?

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/gedit-plugins for 3.10.1-1ubuntu2 from 14.04

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/vivid/universe/base/gedit-plugins for 3.10.1-1ubuntu3 from 14.10

You can either use the graphic installer or install them from terminal with

```
$ dpkg -i ~/Downloads/package.deb
```

Comment: The answer to your question was too long to fit in a comment: I added it as an edit in the main text~