# How do I downgrade Gedit to a previous (3.10.4) Version in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, gedit, downgrade

As the title already says: I have some plug-ins which don't run with gedit 3.18.3 which is shipped with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

How can I downgrade to the version 3.10.4 which was used in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 and get all the plug-ins possible installed?

And how do I revert it back to 3.18.3 if 3.10.4 is not needed any more.

Comment: Great for people hating the new Xenial's Gedit design... which includes myself. I'm probably going to try your procedure some day when I'm on idle.

Comment: @ByteCommander What do you mean, the *new design*? Gedit is the basic editor, I generally use Geany or other more useful ide for serious programming.

Comment: @NoBugs Compare how Gedit looks on 15.10 or previous and on 16.04. The new one lost most of its tool bar and looks ugly IMO.

Comment: @NoBugs: well for me it goes beyond aesthetics. I use some tools that run on top of gedit-plugin and that have not yet been rewritten to take  the new tool bar into account.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**The solution is quite complicated so make sure you read and proceed carefully. As preparation to this make sure you enabled all packet sources so your `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16140883/) and do an upgrade:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

### To install the old version:

Then as a first step, you need to remove the existing version of gedit. To do so run the following commands in your terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
# this installs the build dependencies
sudo apt-get build-dep gedit gedit-plugins
sudo apt-get install moreutils

# this uninstalls the 3.18.3 version of gedit, gedit-dev, 
# gedit-plugins and gedit-common and should get rid of everything else
# installed for gedit
sudo apt-get remove gedit gedit-dev gedit-plugins gedit-common
```

Now prepare a directory to work in. For convenience we do that in our home directory.

```
# creating directory and switching to it
mkdir ~/gedit-downgrade
cd ~/gedit-downgrade
```

Next step is to create a `wget-list` file to make the download easier (you can copy and paste the whole field into your terminal). If you're not using a 64-bit system you might want to find the proper links for i386 [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gedit&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

```
cat > wget-list << "EOF"
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gedit/gedit-common_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gedit/gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gedit/gedit-dev_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gedit-developer-plugins/gedit-developer-plugins_0.5.15-0ubuntu1_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gedit-latex-plugin/gedit-latex-plugin_3.8.0-3build1_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gedit-plugins/gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gedit-r-plugin/gedit-r-plugin_0.8.0.2-Gtk3-Python3-1ubuntu1_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gedit-source-code-browser-plugin/gedit-source-code-browser-plugin_3.0.3-3_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gedit-valencia-plugin/gedit-valencia-plugin_0.8.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs-gedit_0.16-1_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/supercollider/supercollider-gedit_3.6.6~repack-2-1build1_all.deb
EOF
```

Now you have that `wget-list` file, you can download everything in one go by typing `wget -i wget-list`, let the files download and then begin your installation.

Please follow below steps one by one and if you run into dependency errors simply do `sudo apt-get remove <package-name>` which reflects the package giving trouble, then install the dependencies by hand with `sudo apt-get install <package-name>` then do the dpkg line again. Do not, **and I mean do not** run `sudo apt-get -f install` while you're trying this installation: it will mess everything up.

Now, let's begin with the essential packages (tested and working on a clean 16.04 LTS installation):

```
# install gedit-common (essential needed)
sudo dpkg -i gedit-common_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_all.deb

# install gedit (essential needed)
sudo dpkg -i gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb

# install gedit-dev (essential needed)
sudo dpkg -i gedit-dev_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb 

# install gedit-plugins (essential needed)
# here are some steps needed follow them carefully

    # unpacking the .deb file
    sudo dpkg-deb -R gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb tmp

    # editing tmp/DEBIAN/control:
    # change 'python3 (<< 3.5), python3 (>= 3.4~), python3.4' to 'python3 (>= 3.5~), python3.5'
    sed 's/python3 (<< 3\.5), python3 (>= 3\.4~), python3\.4/python3 (>= 3.5~), python3.5/' tmp/DEBIAN/control | sudo sponge tmp/DEBIAN/control

    # editing tmp/DEBIAN/postinst
    # change 'py3compile -p gedit-plugins /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins -V 3.4' to
    # 'py3compile -p gedit-plugins /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins -V 3.5'
    sed 's/3\.4/3.5/' tmp/DEBIAN/postinst | sudo sponge tmp/DEBIAN/postinst

    # packing a new .deb file 
    sudo dpkg-deb -b tmp gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb

    # changing ownership of the new .deb file replace username with your username
    sudo chown username:username gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb

    # removing tmp
    sudo rm -rfv tmp

    # installing it
    sudo dpkg -i gedit-plugins_3.10.1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

The following packages are only optional and you should be able to install them easily, the dependencies to download are given and tested on a clean 16.04 LTS install like the above.

```
# install gedit-developer-plugins (optional)
sudo apt-get install python-pocket-lint
sudo dpkg -i gedit-developer-plugins_0.5.15-0ubuntu1_all.deb

# install gedit-latex-plugin (optional)
sudo apt-get install rubber
sudo dpkg -i gedit-latex-plugin_3.8.0-3build1_all.deb

# install gedit-r-plugin (optional but needs gedit-plugins)
sudo dpkg -i gedit-r-plugin_0.8.0.2-Gtk3-Python3-1ubuntu1_all.deb 

# install gedit-source-code-browser-plugin (optional)
sudo apt-get install ctags
sudo dpkg -i gedit-source-code-browser-plugin_3.0.3-3_all.deb

# install gedit-valencia-plugin (optional)

    # unpacking .deb file
    sudo dpkg-deb -R gedit-valencia-plugin_0.8.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb tmp

    # edit tmp/DEBIAN/control
    # change 'libvala-0.28-0 (>= 0.15.1)' to 'libvala-0.30-0 (>= 0.15.1)'
    # change 'libvte-2.90-9 (>= 1:0.27.2)' to 'libvte-2.91-0 (>= 0.27.2)'
    sed -e 's/libvala-0\.28-0 (>= 0\.15\.1)/libvala-0.30-0 (>= 0.15.1)/' -e 's/libvte-2\.90-9 (>= 1:0\.27\.2)/libvte-2.91-0 (>= 0.27.2)/' tmp/DEBIAN/control | sudo sponge tmp/DEBIAN/control

    # packing a new .deb file 
    sudo dpkg-deb -b tmp gedit-valencia-plugin_0.8.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb

    # changing ownership of the new .deb file replace username with your username
    sudo chown username:username gedit-valencia-plugin_0.8.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb

    # removing tmp
    sudo rm -rfv tmp

    # installing it
    sudo dpkg -i gedit-valencia-plugin_0.8.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb

# install rabbitvcs-gedit (optional)
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-core
sudo dpkg -i rabbitvcs-gedit_0.16-1_all.deb

# install supercollider-gedit (optional)
sudo apt-get install supercollider-language
sudo dpkg -i supercollider-gedit_3.6.6~repack-2-1build1_all.deb
```

Now you have to make sure the packages won't be changed when you run an update, so ensure only to state the packages you have installed:

```
# now protecting this all from upgrading
sudo apt-mark hold gedit-common gedit gedit-dev gedit-developer-plugin gedit-latex-plugin gedit-plugins gedit-r-plugin gedit-source-code-browser-plugin gedit-valencia-plugin rabbitvcs-gedit supercollider-gedit
```

### To reverse the whole process do:

```
# removing protection from upgrades
sudo apt-mark unhold gedit-common gedit gedit-dev gedit-developer-plugin gedit-latex-plugin gedit-plugins gedit-r-plugin gedit-source-code-browser-plugin gedit-valencia-plugin rabbitvcs-gedit supercollider-gedit

# simply do an upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

### Is there a script to do it?:

Yes I made even a script to automate the whole process, you can get it [here](https://github.com/Videonauth/gdowngrade/blob/master/gdowngrade.sh) or by:

```
wget https://github.com/Videonauth/gdowngrade/blob/master/gdowngrade.sh
```

Then to run it:

```
chmod 755 ./gdowngrade.sh
sudo ./gdowngrade.sh
```

This will create a custom file for you called `gupgrade.sh`which allows you to reverse the whole process by simply:

```
sudo ./gupgrade.sh
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Introduction

The script bellow automates installation of gedit 3.10.4 from source. It allows both using the older and newer gedit versions, in case user decides they want to go back to newer gedit.  The script creates `/usr/share/applications/gedit_downgraded.desktop` so that you also can have a nice shortcut to the older gedit.

The usage is farily simple :

```
sudo ./downgrade_gedit.sh [option]
```

Option is either `-i` for install or `-u` for uninstall

The source code is also available on my git, which you can get by running:

```
git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep.git
```

#### Script Source

```
#!/bin/bash
#
###########################################################
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com 
# Date: 
# Purpose: 
#    A script to install version 3.10.4 of gedit on Ubuntu
#    16.04 . Some users are unhappy with new gedit design
#    while others want to downgrade in order to use plugins
#    not available in the new gedit. This script simplifies
#    the downgarde process and building from source.
#    The source is obtained from Gnome's official ftp channels
#    The 3.10.4 is installed separatelly, so if you want to go
#    back to the newer version or used along-side 3.10.4 , you
#    can do so, as the newer version is not uninstalled
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/766055/295286
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04
###########################################################
# Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#    
#     Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is hereby granted
#     without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
#     appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
#     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
#     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
#     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#     FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
#     DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

set -e 
download_gedit()
{
  # Here gnome's official ftp channel is used 
  # feel free to use something else
  # just keep in mind you'd need to make changes to script accordingly
  wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/3.10/gedit-3.10.4.tar.xz
}

extract_gedit()
{
 ARCHIVE="gedit-3.10.4.tar.xz"
 tar --extract --xz --verbose --file "$ARCHIVE" && \
 rm "$ARCHIVE"
}


resolve_depends()
{
 apt-get install intltool libenchant-dev libxml2-dev libgtksourceview-3.0-dev gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev  libpeas-dev  itstool libxml2-utils 
}

make_desktop_file()
{
cat > /usr/share/applications/gedit_downgraded.desktop  <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Gedit(downgraded)
Type=Application 
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/local/bin/gedit %U
EOF
}

make_install_gedit()
{

 cd gedit-3.10.4
 ./configure #PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config)"
 make
 make install
}

install()
{
  # If /opt/gedit-3.10.4 doesn't exist, that's a first run
  # otherwise - create the directory, download and extract
  cd /opt
  if [ ! -d "gedit-3.10.4" ] ; then
      mkdir gedit-3.10.4
      download_gedit
      extract_gedit 
  fi
  resolve_depends
  make_install_gedit
  make_desktop_file
  #mark gedit to be held back
  dpkg --set-selections <<< "gedit hold"
}
uninstall()
{
  cd /opt/gedit-3.10.4
  make uninstall
  hash -r
  [ -e /usr/share/applications/gedit_downgraded.desktop  ] && \
     rm /usr/share/applications/gedit_downgraded.desktop
}

parse_args()
{
  local OPTIND option
  while getopts "iu" option
  do
    case ${option} in
         i) install && exit 0 ;;
         u) uninstall && exit 0 ;; 
         \?) echo "Invalid option -${option}" > /dev/stderr  
    esac
  done
}

main()
{

  if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
     echo "Must specify -i or -u option" > /dev/stderr
     exit 1
  fi

  if [ $( id -u ) -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "Must run as root" > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
  else
     parse_args "$@"
  fi
}

main "$@"
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you have `.deb` packages with `gedit` 3.10 for Ubuntu 16.04 here:

[gedit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/gedit)
[gedit-common](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/gedit-common)

You can download them (choose package depending on your architecture) and install. For instance:

```
sudo dpkg -i gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb gedit-common_3.10.4-0ubuntu13_all.deb
```

(This command will uninstall your current version of `gedit` and install the new one)

And be aware of avoiding that possible future updates upgrade this package (for example, putting them on hold list)