# Hide hold back package from being listed in software updater and apt

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager, held-packages

I'm running 16.04 but downgraded the `gedit` package from 3.18.3 back to version 3.10.4 because of the new ugly and badly usable design, following [this great answer by @Videonauth](https://askubuntu.com/a/766056/367990).

His script installs the old gedit and all available and wanted plugins from an older repository. To prevent the packages from getting upgraded again automatically, he uses `apt-mark hold PACKAGENAMES`.

However, this results in the GUI Software Updater and the various command line tools like `apt list --upgradable` to display these hold packages in the list of upgradable software. Their checkboxes in the Software Updater are greyed out and when trying to run `apt upgrade`, they don't get processed either, but always seeing them in the list is confusing and annoying.

Can I somehow blacklist packages from getting upgraded AND from getting shown in the list of upgradable packages?

Comment: Would like to know this too!