# Tool bar missing for text editor missing after installing 16.04

Tags: text-editor

Tool bar, (title bar, menu bar) missing for text editor after installing 16.04.
I found and entered this information:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

but I have to enter the information every time I open a text editor document.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's happening here. Can you please [edit] your question and include screenshots to the two text editor states? You don't have enough reputation currently to embed images into posts but you can still include links to images in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Gedit's new interface no longer includes a toolbar. It's been somewhat oversimplified. I think pretty much everything is in menus now.

If you really want the toolbar back, you can follow [Videonauth's guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766055/how-do-i-downgrade-gedit-to-a-previous-3-10-4-version-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) to downgrade Gedit, but it's quite complex. Unless you absolutely cannot stand the new look, stay with the current version.