# held broken packages after purging and trying to reinstall skype

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, skype

I use 16.04 64 bit desktop and had `skype` installed from the `partners` repository.

Because of issues with sending messages, I wanted to reinstall it. I ran:

```
sudo apt purge skype
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then I wanted to run:

```
sudo apt install skype
```

But it failed and shows the "You have held broken packages" error.

My only held packages are `gedit` and its plugins, which should not be related to Skype in any way:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
gedit                       hold
gedit-common                hold
gedit-dev                   hold
gedit-developer-plugins     hold
gedit-plugins               hold
```

Trying to install the listed not installing dependencies manually lead me to this chain of commands, which finally results in `apt` suggesting to remove a huge load of packages, including `ubuntu-desktop` and others:

```
bytecommander@BC-AlkaliMetal:~$ sudo apt install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


bytecommander@BC-AlkaliMetal:~$ sudo apt install skype skype-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


bytecommander@BC-AlkaliMetal:~$ sudo apt install skype skype-bin libqtwebkit4:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


bytecommander@BC-AlkaliMetal:~$ sudo apt install skype skype-bin libqtwebkit4:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
                                       Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


bytecommander@BC-AlkaliMetal:~$ sudo apt install skype skype-bin libqtwebkit4:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-tools accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas apturl-common dbus-property-service fonts-droid-fallback fonts-noto-mono
  gir1.2-secret-1 gnome-control-center-data gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-settings-daemon iio-sensor-proxy indicator-network
  libc-ares2 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcolord-gtk1 libconnectivity-qt1 libdbus-cpp5 libdleyna-connector-dbus-1.0-1
  libdleyna-core-1.0-3 libexiv2-14 libgexiv2-2 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgssdp-1.0-3 libgupnp-1.0-4 libgupnp-av-1.0-2
  libhardware2 libhybris libhybris-common1 libhybris-utils libmedia1 libonline-accounts-client1 libonline-accounts-daemon1
  libonline-accounts-qt1 libopus0:i386 libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader libprocess-cpp3 libqmenumodel0 libqofono-qt5-0
  libqt5multimediaquick-p5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libsgutils2-2 libsystemsettings1
  libtheora0:i386 libtrust-store2 libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 media-player-info network-manager-openvpn ofono
  python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-bs4 python-debian python-defer python-html5lib python-lxml python-netifaces
  python-xdg python3-gnupg python3-mako qmenumodel-qml qml-module-qtsysteminfo qml-module-ubuntu-connectivity
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts2 qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0 qtdeclarative5-ofono0.2 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components
  realmd rhythmbox-data shotwell-common sqlite3 system-image-common system-image-dbus ubuntu-keyboard-data ubuntuone-client-data
  ubuntuone-credentials-common urfkill
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu click click-apparmor gcc-5-base:i386 gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8 libasound2:i386
  libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
  libboost-log1.58.0 libbsd0:i386 libclick-0.4-0 libcontent-hub0 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386
  libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgflags2v5 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgoogle-glog0v5 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libhogweed4:i386 libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
  libjson-c2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 liblibertine1
  libllvm3.8:i386 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 libmng2:i386 libmysqlclient20:i386 libnettle6:i386 libogg0:i386
  liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386
  libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-xml:i386
  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386
  libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386
  libubuntu-app-launch2 libubuntu-download-manager-client1 libubuntu-download-manager-common1 libudm-common1 liburcu4
  libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
  libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
  libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 python3-apparmor python3-apparmor-click python3-click-package python3-libapparmor
  qt-at-spi:i386 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 sni-qt:i386
Suggested packages:
  click-reviewers-tools ubuntu-app-launch-tools | upstart-app-launch-tools nas:i386 content-hub gnutls-bin:i386 krb5-doc:i386
  krb5-user:i386 libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 gstreamer1.0-tools:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 jackd2:i386
  libqt4-declarative-folderlistmodel:i386 libqt4-declarative-gestures:i386 libqt4-declarative-particles:i386
  libqt4-declarative-shaders:i386 qt4-qmlviewer:i386 libqt4-dev:i386 libthai0:i386 qt4-qtconfig:i386
Recommended packages:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 xml-core:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED
  apturl cheese evince gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0
  gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-user-guide gnome-video-effects gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3
  gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gufw indicator-bluetooth
  indicator-datetime indicator-power libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libevview3-3
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libqt5webkit5
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer librhythmbox-core9 libtotem0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libyelp0 nautilus-share rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins sessioninstaller shotwell
  signon-ui signon-ui-x11 totem totem-plugins ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-tweak
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-lens-music unity-lens-video update-manager update-notifier yelp zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed
  apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu click click-apparmor gcc-5-base:i386 gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8 libasound2:i386
  libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
  libboost-log1.58.0 libbsd0:i386 libclick-0.4-0 libcontent-hub0 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386
  libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgflags2v5 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgoogle-glog0v5 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libhogweed4:i386 libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 liblibertine1 libllvm3.8:i386 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 libmng2:i386
  libmysqlclient20:i386 libnettle6:i386 libogg0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpng12-0:i386
  libpulse0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script:i386
  libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386
  libqtwebkit4:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386
  libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libubuntu-app-launch2 libubuntu-download-manager-client1
  libubuntu-download-manager-common1 libudm-common1 liburcu4 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386
  libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrender1:i386
  libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 python3-apparmor python3-apparmor-click
  python3-click-package python3-libapparmor qt-at-spi:i386 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 skype skype-bin:i386 sni-qt:i386
0 to upgrade, 133 to newly install, 69 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
Need to get 80,2 MB/80,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 45,0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

How can I install `skype` again?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you try to install it through `apt-get` instead of just `apt`?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Nope, absolutely the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but somehow the problem solved itself.

Probably it went away after installing the recent `gstreamer` package updates...

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm the one who write the script for your held packages its only fair I answer here, you should have gotten a script while you did run my downgrade script called `gupgrade.sh`.

The most hassle free way to solve this situation would be to simply run the `gupgrade.sh` script. Let the system sort out the `skype` and then re-run my downgrade script again ([referring to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766055/how-do-i-downgrade-gedit-to-a-previous-3-10-4-version-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)).

Or if you don't have that script anymore:

```bsh
# unhold the packages
sudo apt-mark unhold gedit-common gedit gedit-dev gedit-developer-plugin gedit-plugins

# removing gedit temporarily
dpkg -r gedit-developer-plugin
dpkg -r gedit-plugins
dpkg -r gedit-dev
dpkg -r gedit
dpkg -r gedit-common

# removing skype and reinstalling it
dpkg -r --force skype
apt-get install skype

# re-run the gedit downgrade
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/7rn0ta39nkfvnj5/gdowngrade.sh
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6eq4zy6dm0wy71/gdowngrade.sh.sum
sha512sum -c gdowngrade.sh.sum
chmod 755 ./gdowngrade.sh
sudo ./gdowngrade.sh
```

Comment: I reverted your gedit downgrade, but that did not help at all...

Comment: That really weird i really thought it was complaining about that, seems I was wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

Running **synaptic** will fix broken packages.  Alternatively `sudo apt-get install -f` will do the same thing.

Comment: Synaptic refuses to install skype for the same reason as apt or apt-get does.